# How to return value from a cell same as it is in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

How to return value from a cell same as it is in VBA?

For example:
A1 has "0.00000" But when I create a double and store this value in that, it stores as "0" But I want it with the same format.

```
Dim i as Double 
i = Range("A1").Value
```

Result: `i = 0`

Comment: A1 probably has value "0" with cell formatting enabled to show "0.00000", am I right?

Comment: So 0.0000 is a bad example, excel automatically converts it to 0 for me at least. If i have a cell format with 0.00.. it works just fine. Maybe try `Format(i, "#.#####0")` .

Comment: Yes, becasue of formatting. So I want to get the same value in vba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the *value* of a cell with the *textural* representation of the value.

If you want the latter then use

```
Dim s as String
s = Range("A1").Text
```

But note that a number is simply a number. The quantity of zeros after the decimal separator or the number of zeros before the number does not change the *value* of that number.